# If an analytic function f is bounded by 1 on a component $G$ of the set {z : |p(z)| < 1} and has a zero at every zero of p, then |f(z)| \leq |p(z)|?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from a past exam:

Let $p(z)$ be a non constant polynomial of $z$. Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a component of the set $\{z : |p(z)| < 1\}$.

(a) Show that $p$ has at least one zero in $G$.

(b) Let $f$ be analytic in $G$ with $|f| \leq 1$. Assume that $f$ has a zero at very zero of $p$ such that the order of vanishing of $f$ is at least that of $p$. Show that $|f(z)| \leq |p(z)|$ and if $z = a$ is a zero of $p$ of order $k$, then $|f^{(k)}(a)| \leq |p^{(k)}(a)|$.

(c) If either $|f(a)| = |p(a)|$ for some $z = a$ that is not a zero of $p$ or if $|f^{(k)}a| = |p^{(k)}(a)|$ for some $z = a$, that is a zero of $p$ of order $k$, then $f(z) = cp(z)$  for some constant $c$.

I am stuck on part (b). I considered the function $g: G \to \mathbb{C}$ defined to be equal to $\frac{f(z)}{p(z)}$ if $z$ is not a zero of $p$, and $\frac{f^{(k)}(z)}{p^{(k)}(z)}$ if $z$ is a zero of $p$ of order $k$, and I am able to show that every singularity of $g$ is removable, and that $g$ is analytic. If $|g| \leq 1$ away from the zeros of $p$, then I can solve parts (b) and (c). However, I am not sure that would hold.

Comment: $|p(z)|=1$ on $\partial G$. Maximum Modulus Principle gives $|f|\leq |p|$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see. Thank you!